# How can I get Presto host:port configuration?

Tags: presto

I can use `presto-cli` to execute queries like this:

```
$ presto-cli
presto> show catalogs;
 Catalog 
---------
 hive    
 system  
(2 rows)
```

However, if I try with:

```
$ presto-cli --server localhost:8080
presto> show catalogs;
Error running command: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
```

How can I know the host/port configuration of the server to explicitly pass it as parameter?

Comment: Presto CLI uses `localhost:8080` as the default for `--server` parameter. Are you using a modified version of the Presto CLI? What happens if you download Presto CLI 336 from https://prestosql.io/download.html?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Thanks for your comment. It may be modified, and it may be using environment variables or configuration files, I don't know. Unfortunately, I am unable to download and install Presto, since I have no privileges on the server nor Internet connection. Isn't it possible to know which server `presto-cli` is using in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`presto-cli` prints defaults when invoked with `--help`:

```
$ presto-cli --version
Presto CLI 334

$ presto-cli --help | grep -A2 -e --server
...
--
        --server <server>
            Presto server location (default: localhost:8080)
```

On EMR, however, `presto-cli` is a wrapper script. See @Peque answer for details.

Comment: Yeah, the `--help` is the first thing I read, and that is what I got the `localhost:8080` to try as parameter. It seems the `--help` shows `localhost:8080`, but that is not working when passed as parameter. Any idea? Maybe that default is hard-coded in the help, but does not represent the default in the installation I got? :-/

Comment: I found (and posted) the answer. It seems the configuration was being loaded from `/etc/presto/conf/config.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

On AWS EMR, the configuration could be loaded from:

```
/etc/presto/conf/config.properties
```

In particular, the port is being set as `http-server.http.port` in that file.

Comment: Presto CLI does not do that. Your `presto-cli` must be some wrapper script. I edited the answer to highlight that.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Thanks. ^^